# Multiple autosuggest inputs-Closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, input, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'm using this plugin to select multiple items with autosuggestions.

[Drew Wilson's Auto Suggest JQuery plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

I need to have more than one input of this type with different items. 
I use different datasources and classes to each input so they dont use the same data. 
I've already tried using two inputs with the autosuggest plugin. However, when i do this, only the last input works and the others become simple textboxes.

Comment: Example of your code would be helpful

Comment: This plugin was last updated in 2010, so many things may be depreciated. Use jQuery UI autocomplete.

Comment: well, i guess i'll go with jQuery UI autocomplete. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I realised [Drew Wilson's Auto Suggest JQuery plugin](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin) doesn't work with more than one autosuggest input, I guess. Best option to solve this is to use [Jquery's UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).